# Jenkins. Change version in file and commit

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have next Jenkins task. We would like to read file from cloned repo, increment version described in that file and push to the same repo.

File have content like:

```
$ cat version
some_version=3.1.9
```

Only last digit needs to be changed and new file should be pushed. So after job run this digit should be 3.1.10, then 3.1.11 and so on.

I've managed to do that with bash:

```
$ VAR_OLD=$(cat version | grep 'some_version=')
$ VAR_NEW=$(cat version | grep 'some_version=' | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{++$NF; print}')

$ sed -i "s/$VAR_OLD/$VAR_NEW/g" version

$ cat version
some_version=3.1.10
```

But I think Jenkins can do that by itself via Groovy (We are using Jenkins pipeline plugin). I don't like to use just bash, it's not native. Could somebody help me with pseudocode?